# Is it possible to have a TypeScript declaration-merged enum implement an interface?

Tags: typescript, enums

Let's say I have this enum:

```js
enum SomeEnum {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
    D = 3
}
```

I've added a member called bits to SomeEnum by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in this way:

```js
namespace SomeEnum {
    readonly bits: number = 2;
}
```

Just to make it clear, bits is the number of bits the values of SomeEnum's consist of.
Now, let's say I have another enum, OtherEnum, with different values but also with a member called bits.

```js
enum OtherEnum {
    X = 0,
    Y = 1
}

namespace OtherEnum {
    readonly bits: number = 1;
}
```

As you can see, both of them are enums with a bits member. Therefore, I would love to be able to create a base interface, HasBits, whose only member is bits and which both of the enums "implement".

```js
interface HasBits {
    bits: number;
}
```

My question is, is there any way in which I can do something so both enums are turned into siblings by both "implementing" an interface?

I would like to use some other generic class that expects a type which holds a bits member, but I want this type to be an enum. Can it be implemented? Should I just implement these enums as classes with static values that implement a common interface with static readonly bits member?

Comment: I don't understand what "siblings" means here.

Comment: I don't see that possible today. The closest you can get is using union type.

Comment: Can you just declare that your generic class accepts the interface `HasBits`? You will still get type checking, and both of your enums will be able to be passed in because even though they don't declare that they implement the interface they still meet the requirements of the interface.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Sorry, I'm used to Python and forgot sibling is usually relevant to Python only. What I meant is a 2 classes inheriting from the same base class/interface.

Comment: Thanks to you both.. I dropped the idea of this implementation. It's obviously a bad practice in the first place as enums in TypeScript cannot extend or implement any other base class becasue an enum is not a real type in JavaScript.